# Powershell script to upload a folder and all its children to the FTP server has multiple errors

Tags: powershell, azure, ftp

Hi I have found this script to help me copy an entire folder with all its nested content to my FTP server, which is an Azure hosted Windows Server 2012.

Here is the script:

```
$a = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$a.WindowTitle = "Sync Folder To Ftp"

$ftp = "ftp://igtestvm1.cloudapp.net/IQS FTP Content/IQSWS"
$localDirectory = "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8b19187411566286\IQS Web Server"
$user = "u"
$pass = "p"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)
$webclient.UsePassive = $False
$Files = get-childitem $localDirectory -recurse -force 
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $LocalFile = $File.FullName

    $RemoveDirectory = $LocalFile.Replace($localDirectory,"")
    $ChangeSlashes = $RemoveDirectory.Replace('\', '/')
    $RemoveSpaces = $ChangeSlashes.Trim()
    $RemoteFile = $ftp+$RemoveSpaces
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($RemoteFile) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $LocalFile)

    Write-Host "Getting $File from $localDirectory" -Foreground "Red"
    Write-Host "Puting $File to $ftp" -Foreground "Yellow"
} 

Write-Host "Finished Sync to $ftp" -Foreground "Green"
```

Now i get the following errors when i run the script:

```
Property 'UsePassive' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
```

How would i fix this one?

Comment: To start off, the System.Net.WebClient does not have a UsePassive property, so remove the line $webclient.UsePassive = $False in order to avoid the first error.

Comment: ok thanks but which namespace does have the .UsePassive?

Comment: System.Net.FtpWebRequest

Comment: so how would i add that because if i remove the .UsePassive i get error number 2?

Comment: I haven't done that myself before and I don't have an ftp server in order to test on. Try the method from this link: http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/11/powershell-ftp-upload-and-download/
hope that helps